# Check if hasClass and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and everytime one `div` is on focus is added the class `swiper-slide-visible`.
I'm trying to show a another div depending on what item is on focus.
My problem is the Jquery doesnt check when I rotate it and if I use While my browser stop to work.

```
 <div class="swiper-slide pag1"> <h1>A</h1> </div>
 <div class="swiper-slide pag2"> <h1>B</h1> </div>
 <div class="swiper-slide pag3"> <h1>C</h1> </div>
```

---

```
 <div class="conteudo">
  <p class="divA">Conteudo DIV A</p>
  <p class="divB">Conteudo DIV B</p>
  <p class="divC">COnteudo DIV C</p> 
</div>
```

---

```
 if ($(".pag1").hasClass("swiper-slide-visible")) {
  $(".divA").show();
}
if ($(".pag2").hasClass("swiper-slide-visible")) {
  $(".divB").show();
}
if ($(".pag3").hasClass("swiper-slide-visible")) {
  $(".divC").show();
}
```

Comment: What slider do you use?

Comment: Why not just `if ($('.pag1.swiper-slide-visible').size())  $('.divA').show()`?

Comment: Where is the Javascript that you posted going? Is it inside an event handler somewhere? If so, please post the full code.

Comment: @niels Swiper Idangerous http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Comment: @BradChristie Cuz if I do this, it wont clean when i rotate.

Comment: Your code is executed once, you should listen to an event. The library has [callback functions](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php).

Comment: You need to tell it to look, it will not magically keep running.

Comment: @BlackSheep Ok it worked! Tks for tip :P